# Using a keyboard shortcut to execute a script

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, scripts

Hello I am a linux newbie trying to set up a keyboard shortcut to execute a script I have. The script functions as desired, and is

```
#!/bin/bash

livestreamer twitch.tv/arteezy best
```

This opens up VLC player to watch a live stream of a game.

Now, I want to make it even easier and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (or whatever) to open up the script.

I have the script located in `/home/username/livestreamer/ArteezyHigh.sh`

So I go to the "Custom Shortcuts" area and add a new shortcut.

In the command area I tried putting the location, but it did not run the script. I tried some version of `-gnome -e "livestreamer twitch.tv/arteezy best"` to run the terminal with the command, this did not work either. I am not sure what I am missing, and would like to be able to open the stream using a custom hotkey. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you run this `chmod +x /home/username/livestreamer/ArteezyHigh.sh` to make your script executable?